# WPF Binding in Custom Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, custom-controls

I have a CustomControl in WPF.

```
[TemplatePart(Name = ControlSaveButtonName, Type = typeof(Button))]
[TemplatePart(Name = ControlCancelButtonName, Type = typeof(Button))]
[TemplatePart(Name = ControlPanelName, Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class BaseEditEntityControl : Control
{
    public const string ControlSaveButtonName = "PART_SaveButton";
    public const string ControlCancelButtonName = "PART_CancelButton";
    public const string ControlPanelName = "PART_Panel";

    static BaseEditEntityControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BaseEditEntityControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BaseEditEntityControl)));
    }

    private Button _saveButtonControl;
    public Button SaveButtonControl
    {
        get { return _saveButtonControl; }
    }
    private Button _cancelButtonControl;
    public Button CancelButtonControl
    {
        get { return _cancelButtonControl; }
    }
    private Panel _panelControl;
    public Panel PanelControl
    {
        get { return _panelControl; }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Entity", typeof(object), typeof(BaseEditEntityControl));
            //, new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            //{
            //    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
            //    PropertyChangedCallback = BaseEntityPropertyChanged
            //});

    public object Entity
    {
        get { return GetValue(EntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntityProperty, value); FillPropertyControls(); }
    }

    public BaseEditEntityControl()
    {
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
         base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _saveButtonControl = GetTemplateChild(ControlSaveButtonName) as Button;
        _cancelButtonControl = GetTemplateChild(ControlCancelButtonName) as Button;
        _panelControl = GetTemplateChild(ControlPanelName) as Panel;

        if (_saveButtonControl != null) _saveButtonControl.Click += SaveButton_Click;
        if (_cancelButtonControl != null) _cancelButtonControl.Click += CancelButton_Click;
    }

    public void FillPropertyControls()
    { 
        //Some Code
    }

    //private static void BaseEntityPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    var baseEntityControl = d as BaseEditEntityControl;
    //    if (baseEntityControl == null) return;
    //
    //    baseEntityControl.Entity = e.NewValue as BaseEntity;
    //}
}
```

Control template:

```
<Style x:Key="PassportEntityEditControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type base:BaseEditEntityControl}">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type base:BaseEditEntityControl}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Panel" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Entity, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=base:BaseEditEntityControl}}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Control using:

```
<Style TargetType="propertyControls1:PersonPassportPropertyControl">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="propertyControls1:PersonPassportPropertyControl">
                <Grid ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <base:BaseEditEntityControl x:Name="PART_Value" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                      Entity="{Binding PropertyBinding, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=propertyControls1:PersonPassportPropertyControl}}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource PassportEntityEditControlStyle}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

PersonPassportPropertyControl also a custom control.

PROBLEM: TextBox filled, but 'Entity set' and FillPropertyControls not called. If uncomment PropertyChangedCallback then BaseEntityPropertyChanged called.

Comment: Your observation is correct, a dependency property neither calls the setter nor the getter by design. That's why your commented code is correct. The only valid code in the setter/getter is SetValue/GetValue.

Answer (score 1):

Bindings do not use get and set accessors.

change the Entity property the following way:

```
    //Entity Dependency Property
    public object Entity
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(EntityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntityProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EntityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Entity", typeof(object), 
        typeof(BaseEditEntityControl),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null),
        (d, e) => { FillPropertyControls(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how it's designed to work. It's clearly mentioned in documentation as well that XAML bypasses property wrappers and directly call `GetValue` and `SetValue`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx):

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The WPF XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties. **This effectively
>   bypasses the property wrappers. When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.**

Use **`PropertyChangeCallback`** instead to place your code which you want to execute whenever dependency property changes.